# I am building a VOD service. The videos have been stored on S3 buckets. How do I decrease the latency while fetching the videos?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, video-streaming, video-processing, http-live-streaming

The backend is in node and front end is built using react. I used getObject to fetch the video from the bucket and then used createReadStream() on it and then pipe the response.

```
s3
    .getObject({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: filename,
      Range: 'bytes=0-20582912',
    })
    .createReadStream()
    .pipe(res);
```

Can someone tell me how do I introduce byte range fetches in it? I want the video to be divided into chunks and then send it to the video player in the front end. I am also using mp4, would using HLS help in this case? Or would creating a presigned-url and then sending that to the video-player help?

I tried the above the code but I am hoping less latency and immediate buffering.

Comment: You can introduce chunking on the frontend side of things where the frontend decides requests the chunk from the backend. So: frontend says I want 0-1283 and frontend keeps track of the top value, and asks for the next whenever needed.

Comment: Just sign the URL and send it to the client directly. No need to proxy it like you're doing here.